# What does Python 3.2 "with/as" do

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement

I'm learning Python, and I'm trying out the `with **** as ****:` statement. I figure it works much like C#'s `using(****) {`, but I'm afraid I'm following outdated examples.

This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-

import pprint

pow = 1, 2, 3

with pprint.pprint as pprint:
    pprint(pow)
```

I assume what's happening here is `pprint` in my small closure is an alias for the `pprint.pprint` function. I'm getting a weird error though:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    with pprint.pprint as pprint:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

So now I'm thinking I'm using syntax from an older version of Python like I did earlier (`print "Hello"`)

Why isn't my code working as expected?

Comment: These are not the droids you are looking for ...

Comment: to be fair, even though your examples are apparently outdates (or altogether wrong misleading to begin with -- pretty sure Python never worked like that), your intuition about the C# parallel (as well as the inaccuracy of the examples you came across). I like to think of C#'s `IDisposable` + `using(... = ...)` sugar syntax as analogous to Python's `Context Manager` + `with ... as ...` sugar syntax. and they're both sugar for `try ... finally` I'm I'm not mistaken, perfect parallel!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `with` statement isn't intended to do what you expect. It uses the "context manager protocol", and as such, expects to be passed a [context manager](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers).

To create an alias, just assign it to a new variable:

```
import pprint

pow = 1, 2, 3

pp = pprint.pprint
pp(pow)
```

Comment: Or `from pprint import pprint`.  Or `from pprint import pprint as pp`

Comment: I assumed the alias had to be local to a block, seeing how the OP tried to use the `with` statement. If that's not necessary, renaming at the import is indeed the best solution.

Comment: You can read more on the "as" statement here: https://pythontic.com/concepts/keywords/as

This should make the difference between "import .. as .." and "with .. as .." clear.

Answer (score 18):

`with` doesn't work like that.

It's designed to automatically clean up an object at the end of a block, e.g. instead of

```
file = open('foo.txt')
# do stuff
close(file)
```

You can do

```
with open('foo.txt') as file:
    # do stuff
```

and the close happens automatically.

See [PEP 343 -- The "with" Statement](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) for details and [What's New in Python 2.5 - PEP 343](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-343-the-with-statement) for some more examples of how you can use it.

Comment: It's not that `with` is expected to clean it up, it's that the context manager is expected to clean itself up, and `with` manages its lifetime appropriately.

Comment: Yes, but to answer a simple question with details about context managers and `__exit__` would be too confusing IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

You're using it expecting it to alias an existing name, but [in Python `with` expects to be passed a context manager](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/). `pprint.pprint` is not a context manager.

Answer (score 2):

Aliasing is not what `with` is for. What you probably want is this:

```
from pprint import pprint

pow = 1, 2, 3
pprint(pow)
```